# Slice DataFrame based on Multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, filter

I hope you are doing well. I have a question regarding a DataFrame in Python.

| Company | Job Title | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Founder | Steve Jobs |
| Apple | Co-Founder | Steve Wozniak |
| Microsoft | Founder | Bill Gates |
| Microsoft | Co-Founder | Paul Allen |
| Paypal | Co-Founder | Peter Thiel |
| Tesla | Board Member | Larry Ellison |
| Tesla | CFO | Zach Kirkhorn |
| Snapchat | Devan Fearman | Devan Fearman |

I would like to filter and create a new Dataframe which keeps only the rows based on the following conditions:

1. if Founder then keep row
2. if can't find Founder then Co-Founder
3. if can't find Co-Founder then Board Member
4. if can't find Board Member then Board Member CFO

Drop all other rows from the Dataframe. Note that I am allowed to have only 1 row per company.

Therefore I would like to have the following output below:

| Company | Job Title | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Founder | Steve Jobs |
| Microsoft | Founder | Bill Gates |
| Paypal | Co-Founder | Peter Thiel |
| Tesla | Board Member | Larry Ellison |

I am sure there is a way to do this using a loop function, however since I am very new to Python this is still very hard for me. I am open to using all libraries like pandas and numpy. Please explain your code as clearly as possible.

Hope to hear from you soon. Thank you and please let me know if I was not clear with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of  Job Title ranking. Map to the Job Title. Drop any Job Title not in the rank. Sort values and drop duplicated companies.

```
 d={'Founder':1,'Co-Founder':2,'Board Member':3,'Board Member CFO':4}
 df=df.assign(rank=df['JOB TITLE'].map(d)).sort_values(by='rank').dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['COMPANY']).drop('rank', 1)

     COMPANY     JOB TITLE    PERSON NAME  rank
0      Apple       Founder     Steve Jobs     1
2  Microsoft       Founder     Bill Gates     1
4     Paypal    Co-Founder    Peter Thiel     2
5      Tesla  Board Member  Larry Ellison     3
```

Comment: Thank you will try and follow up if I have more questions.

Comment: Happy to offer any explanations if needed.

Comment: Let's say that Paypal had another Co-Founder named Mike. Which Co-Founder would your code select? If it would pick the 1st occurrence then is there a way to make it pick randomly amongst either one of the choices? So for some cases, it picks the 1st Co-Founder, in others it picks the 2nd or the 3rd Co-Founder provided that we don't have data for the Founder.

Comment: @Ammar Kamran the common thing is that if an answer is suitable for initial question asked at least an upvote is given before the question is modified. For your modified question, we can sort_values by the column name or a combination of other columns to achieve a suitable outcome. I don't think we can achieve a random choice without doing a loop. Please consider upvoting for answers achieving initial outcome in appreciation of efforts by others to help you

Comment: your code also worked thank you.

My apologies, I am still very new to the community and learning the common practises as I go along.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.Category` here:

```
df['Job Title'] = pd.Categorical(df['Job Title'].str.strip(),
                                 categories=['Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Board Member', 'CFO'],
                                 ordered=True
                                )

df.sort_values(['Job Title']).drop_duplicates('Company').dropna()
```

Output:

```
      Company     Job Title    Person Name
0      Apple        Founder     Steve Jobs
2  Microsoft        Founder     Bill Gates
4     Paypal     Co-Founder    Peter Thiel
5      Tesla   Board Member  Larry Ellison
```

Comment: Quang Hoang Let's say that Paypal had another Co-Founder named Mike.

Which Co-Founder would your code select? If it would pick the 1st occurrence then is there a way to make it pick randomly amongst either one of the choices?

So for some cases, it picks the 1st Co-Founder, in others it picks the 2nd or the 3rd Co-Founder provided that we don't have data for the Founder.

Comment: `df.sample(frac=1).sort_values(['Job Title'], kind='mergesort')...`

Comment: @ Quang Hoang Thank you, however as I understand mergesort is not exactly random.

Is there a different way to do this by importing random?

This post might be something similar however I can't connect the dots.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951537/introducing-some-randomness-with-sorting-in-python

Comment: @AmmarKamran randomness comes from `sample`. You're right that `mergesort` is stable. And using `mergesort` on `sample` is to reserve the randomness created by `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating an extra column `Aux` which helps with the `Job Title` priority. Let's suppose your sample dataframe is defined as `df`:

```
aux = {'Job Title':['Founder','Co-Founder','Board Member','CFO'],'Rank':[1,2,3,4]}
df['Rank'] = df['Job Title'].merge(aux,on='Job Title')
df_filtered = df.groupby('COMPANY')['Rank'].min().reset_index().merge(aux,on='Rank').drop(columns='Rank')
```

Comment: I will try this approach as well thank you.